# C++11: Unable to infer template argument

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, algebraic-data-types

the line:

```cpp
    auto test = add<Suc < Suc < Suc < Suc < Zero > > > > > (three, one);
```

if I replace with:

```cpp
    auto test = add(three, one);
```

I get error candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'W', using a Clang compiler with std=c++11
I can't imagine any other value satisfying W for it, is there a way to fix it?

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class Nat {
};

class Zero : public Nat<Zero> {
};

template<typename T, 
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Nat<T>, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
class Suc : public Nat<Suc<T> > {
 public:
  T val;
  explicit Suc(T v): val(v) {}
};

template<typename T>
Suc<T> suc(T val) {
    Suc<T> next(val);
    return next; 
}

template<typename W, typename U, typename V,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Nat<W>, W>::value>::type* = nullptr,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Nat<U>, U>::value>::type* = nullptr,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Nat<V>, V>::value>::type* = nullptr
    >
W add(Suc<U> m, V n) {
    Suc<V> next (n);
    return add<W>(m.val, next);
}

template<typename V>
V add(Zero m, V n) {
    return n;
}

int main() {

    Zero zero;
    auto one = suc(zero);
    auto two = suc(one);
    auto three = suc(two);
    auto four = suc(three);

    auto test = add<Suc < Suc < Suc < Suc < Zero > > > > > (three, one);

    return 0;
}
```

Console output:

```
c++ -std=c++11 main.cc

main.cc:48:17: error: no matching function
      for call to 'add'
    auto test = add(three, one);
                ^~~
main.cc:35:3: note: candidate function
      template not viable: no known
      conversion from 'Suc<Suc<Suc<Zero,
      nullptr>, nullptr>, nullptr>' to
      'Zero' for 1st argument
V add(Zero m, V n) {
  ^
main.cc:29:3: note: candidate template
      ignored: couldn't infer template
      argument 'W'
W add(Suc<U> m, V n) {
  ^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message is telling you why:

> main.cc:29:3: note: candidate template
>        ignored: couldn't infer template
>        argument 'W'

The return type is a template argument, but the compiler can't deduce a return type from the function arguments, you have to specify it.

But, `decltype` can help you compute what that return type should be:

```
template<typename U, typename V>
auto add(Suc<U> m, V n) -> decltype(add(m.val, Suc<V>(n))) {
    Suc<V> next (n);
    return add(m.val, next);
}
```

Comment: Of course I understood that. but if you try any other value for W it will fail to compile - because there is no matching specialization. Is there a way I can hint to compiler that this is the only valid return type?

Comment: I'm sorry if I don't understand completely. There can only be one return type, the one you use in the function signature. Return anything else from the function body, and the compiler will complain.